# Interface-sensitive operations in Java

Tags: java, interface

This is my overall workflow. First create an interface:

```
public interface foo {
   void bar(Baz b);
}
```

Then make, for example, a vector with *different* objects that all implement said interface:

```
myVector.add(new Ex);  //both Ex and Why implement foo.
myVector.add(new Why);
```

And finally, use the interface:

```
for(int i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++) {
    myVector.get(i).bar(b);
}
```

However, for obvious reasons, this produces a compile time error:

> The method bar() is undefined for the type Object

Casting won't work because Ex and Why aren't related. Try-catch casting to Ex and then Why is a horrible work-around. Making both Ex and Why extend Bar_doers also doesn't sound succinct either, as that would be doing away with interfaces.

How can I perform operations that care about whether an Object implements a given interface, not whether an object is of a given class?

Comment: Casting to `foo` isn't possible why?

Comment: if you have written the interface, you can add the method foo() in the interface. Then it should work.

Comment: FYI: It's idiomatic for all types to start with a capital letter; so it should be `Foo`, not `foo` for your interface.

Comment: Also, did you mean your example to call `bar` rather than `foo`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to read about [*generics*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Assuming you were using a standard Java container, then the solution in your case is to define `myVector` thus:

```
List<foo> myVector = new ArrayList<foo>();
```

Comment: But in this case, he won't be able to add Why and Ex both types of Object.

Comment: what if `myVector` isn't a `List` but rather some library type that doesn't support generics?

Comment: @Pankaj: If they implement `Foo`, then they can be added to this list.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Then you have a problem, and can't do it this way!  But probably the best solution is to not use that library.

Comment: Yes correct, but since Foo interface don't have foo() method, he wont be able to call it. It will result in Compile time error.

Comment: @Pankaj: I'm assuming the OP made a typo, and that he really meant to call `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Cast them to your interface and it will work:

```
for(int i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++) {
    ((foo)myVector.get(i)).foo(b);
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yep.  Generics is a better way, but it sounds like the OP could use some help on basic inheritance first.

Comment: This works but isn't as safe, i.e. it allows things w/o foo to make into myVector.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface A {
    public void myMethod();
}




public class B implements A {

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class C implements A {

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new B());
        list.add(new C());

        for(A obj : list){
            obj.myMethod();
        }
    }

}
```

Above will print:

```
B
C
```

Comment: This is correct and can be used to show a novice examples of interface and classes, however the answer is longer than necessary for me.